# how to create page 404 error in custom PHP MVC?

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect, http-status-code-404

In my custom PHP MVC, how can I redirect the error page to page404 in .htaccesss?  For example, `example.com/controller/method`, when controller or method not exist, it has to redirect to page404 but I don't know how to do it.

In .htaccess script, I've used
`ErrorDocument 404 /page404.php`
page404 is in root and inside of it I put
`example.com/index/page404`, but it does not work.  How do I fix this?

Comment: you can do it on routing code, all you need is to check if the url route is pointing in your function or route array

Comment: Use your router. What have you tried?

Comment: In my custom system I have a `front controller` which does some initial checks, parses and santises any request data and sets up a load of data to be injected etc.  In here I have a service that checks if a route is valid and if any expected data is there.  If not I set the response code to 404 (or whatevers relevant) and then load up my lost page/lost message (depending if its an api call or a Web page request)

Comment: @Jerson I've done it and there is no problem, but I want to do this by .htaccess, because when I use simple routing, google indexing find my page404 as sitemap page and throw an error about the format of it

Comment: @jibsteroos I mentioned in above

Comment: then don't include it using robots.txt disallow that page

Comment: "but I want to do this by .htaccess" - You can't do something like this in `.htaccess`. There's no way in `.htaccess` to determine whether the request should result in a 404, since this is determined by your PHP code.

Answer (score 1):

you can where you had analyzed the format of the route, check if this method in that controller exists or not, if there is no method or controller, redirect that to your 404 pages.

an example for controller:

```php
if (file_exists($controller . '.php')) {
   // Controller does exist
} else {
   header("Location: {path_of_views}/404.php");
}
```

an example for method:

```php
if (method_exists($controller, $methodName)) {
   // Method does exist
} else {
    header("Location: {path_of_views}/404.php");
}
```

UPDATE:

add `ErrorDocument` to your .htaccess:

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.example.com/error.html
```

you can read more in this [link](https://ubiq.co/tech-blog/redirect-404-homepage-using-htaccess/).

Comment: I've done it and there is no problem, but I want to do this by .htaccess because when I use simple routing, google indexing find my page404 as a sitemap page and throw an error about the format of it

Comment: why you want to redirect it else you can include the whole 404page html inorder to avoid google indexing the url

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using a routing code in PHP. If you want to do it with the .htaccess anyway, you should check the apache configuration first and set it to "Allowoverride All" on the Directory to authorize .htaccess files.

Comment: I've sent it as response you can see

Comment: Can you access to the apache log (assuming you use apache) ? What happen when you try to reach a 404 page ?

Comment: unfortunately, I don't know how I do it